# How to get meta box values - WP tuts tutorial

Tags: metabox, post-meta

I did these tree tutorials to create custom metaboxes.

- wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-1-intro-and-basic-fields/
- wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-2-advanced-fields/
- wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-3-extra-fields/

but i don't know how to call values from individual fields. I used this php script

```
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
echo $meta;
```

but id doesn't work. Does someone know what I do wrong.

here is my function.php
http://www.4shared.com/file/8jmKqGFY/functions.html?

and here is my index.php
http://www.4shared.com/file/iAWwZim7/index.html?

Comment: replace `$field['id']` with the actual id you gave the field

Comment: I did this, but it display nothing

Comment: Can you show us your full loop code?

Comment: here is my functions.php http://www.4shared.com/file/8jmKqGFY/functions.html?

and here is my index.php

http://www.4shared.com/file/iAWwZim7/index.html?

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct meta key? Maybe try `print_r( get_post_custom_keys($post_id) );` and you will see all the meta keys associated with that post. (Also for code sharing, I would suggest something like [Pastie](http://pastie.org/))

Comment: Please paste your code directly into your question -- at least the relevant parts.

Answer (score 3):

After reviewing your code there are a couple of things you need to change depending on where the meta content is being held.

If you try

```
$meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_text', TRUE );
echo 'The meta content is: ' . $meta;`
```

That should give you the appropriate meta.

You are calling this function on the page content, so unless the meta content is being held there nothing will be output.

Hope that helps!

Comment: no it doesn't work but I figured it out :) Solution is this

$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['custom_text'], true);
echo $meta[custom_text][0];


Thx for your help

Comment: Don't for to accept the answer so in the future people know how to get to the solution you did. Also it's polite.

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer. It helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not on a template file where you can't use `get_the_ID()` (say you're on a plugin file), first get a pointer to the post object associated with the meta content and then use `$post->ID`.

For example, if you used `add_meta_box` to define a function displaying the meta box (say `display_meta_box`), you can retrieve the meta box value thus:

```
function display_meta_box( $post ) {
  $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, "meta_key", true); 
  echo "<input name='x' value='$meta' />";
}
```